# Fundamental typedef operand syntax

Tags: c++, c, typedef

Given:

```
typedef type-declaration synonym;
```

I can see how:

```
typedef long unsigned int size_t;
```

declares `size_t` as a synonym for `long unsigned int`, however I (know it does but) can't see *exactly* how:

```
typedef int (*F)(size_t, size_t);
```

declares `F` as a synonym for `pointer to function (size_t, size_t) returning int`

typedef's two operands `(type-declaration, synonym)` in the first example are `long unsigned int` and `size_t`.

What are the two arguments to typedef in the declaration of `F` or are there perhaps overloaded versions of typedef?

If there is a relevant distinction between C and C++ please elaborate otherwise I'm primarily interested in C++ if that helps.

Comment: Just to clarify source of initial given syntax is from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05w82thz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: don't believe everything Microsoft tells you ;-)

Comment: Function pointer declarations are some of the weirdest syntax in C. The only thing I've seen that was weirder was pointer-to-member syntax in C++... And that's because it resembles C function pointer syntax.

Comment: @Steve: Thanks :) I wouldn't dream of it: suspicion is usually healthy in my experience which actually led to this question in this instance

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Type declarations using `typedef` are the same as corresponding variable declarations, just with `typedef` prepended.  So,

```
        int x; // declares a variable named 'x' of type 'int'
typedef int x; // declares a type named 'x' that is 'int'
```

It's exactly the same with function pointer types:

```
        int(*F)(size_t); // declares a variable named F of type 'int(*)(size_t)'
typedef int(*F)(size_t); // declares a type named 'F' that is 'int(*)(size_t)'
```

It's not a "special case;" that's just what a function pointer type looks like.

Comment: This is very useful thanks, I can immediately see the difference now, what is still slightly confusing is the 'two arguments', am I right in clarifing that for `typedef int(*F)(size_t);` there is only one argument to typedef?

Comment: @Peter:  It's not really an argument at all; it's just the syntax of a declaration.  `int(*)(size_t)` is the type of a pointer to a function that returns an `int` and that has a single parameter of type `size_t`.  A function to which such a pointer points must take a single argument (of type `size_t`), but that's the only "argument" here.

Comment: @Peter: `typedef` isn't a function, it doesn't take arguments. It turns a variable declaration into a type declaration.

Comment: I can see now how to read a type declaration using typedef correctly, this wasn't obvious from several different documentation sources I've read up to now - thank you!

Answer (score 7):

That's not the formal syntax of a typedef, it's just one of the patterns which it can take. In the C standard 6.7.1, `typedef` is syntactically defined as a storage-class specifier (like `extern` or `static`). It modifies a declaration, so that the declaration declares a type alias instead of an object.

`typedef` isn't either a function or an operator, so notions of "argument", "operand" or "overloading" don't apply to it. It just tells the compiler what kind of declaration you're making.

In C++, `typedef` is syntactically defined as a *decl-specifier*, it is not a *storage-class-specifier*. *storage-class-specifiers* are also *decl-specifiers*, and so is `friend`. I don't think this makes any practical difference, it's another way of saying the same thing C says, but it's 7.1 of the C++ standard if you want to have a look for yourself. I confess it's baffling me for the time being.

Comment: This is also very helpful although I could still do with clarification on the number of arguments to typedef, is it worth including the correct syntax of typedef here or perhaps a link to elaborate on your first sentence?

Comment: @Peter: `typedef` doesn't have any arguments, just like `static` doesn't have arguments, or `const` doesn't have arguments. It doesn't have it's own syntax, either. It's a modifier stuck on the beginning of a declaration, so it's part of the declaration syntax. The declaration syntax and semantics basically occupy the entirety of chapters 7 and 8 of the C++ standard.

Comment: I think C++ has that distinction because you can put storage class specifiers inside decl specifiers, but not the other way around.  E.g. 'typedef const static int foo;' is okay but 'static typedef const foo int;' is not.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial assumption about typedef syntax having the

```
typedef type-declaration synonym;
```

structure is absolutely incorrect. Typedef syntax does not have that structure and never had.

Typedef syntax is that of an ordinary declaration, just like any other declaration in C language. Keyword `typedef` is simply a declaration specifier that indicates that the name declared is a typedef name, and not a variable, function designator or something else.

You can use multiple declarators in the same typedef declaration, for example

```
typedef int TInt, *TIntPtr, (*TIntFuncPtr)(void), TIntArr10[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking of `typedef` as an operation which takes two parameters (the type and the synonym) think of it as a type qualifier.  To declare a variable named `F` which was a function pointer accepting two `size_t` parameters and returning `int` you would have just:

```
int (*F)(size_t, size_t);
```

Add the type qualifier `typedef` and instead of declaring a variable, you've declared a type alias instead.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` is using the declaration syntax.

The function pointer `typedef` is the same as you would use to declare a function pointer.  Except in that case you are declaring a type, not variable.