# Compilation error in a very simple C struct

Tags: c

```
typedef struct test { 
    int a;
}; 

int main(void) { 
test t; 
t.a = 3; 
}
```

The above does not compile. However when I change the struct to:

```
typedef struct {
    int a; 
}test;
```

Everything works fine. Why is this? I have seen plenty of code examples where the struct is on the same line as the typedef but it isn't compiling for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions

Comment: See POWs answer below, you're missing the the alias-name.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Based on the answers I doubt it's legal C. Im getting errors on gcc

Comment: @user2202911: Sorry, I was addressing only the initial declaration. The initial declaration is legal C, but it does not declare a type name because there is no name in the position where a name should be. When you ask about something that “does not compile”, you should include the actual compiler error message.

Comment: I understand now. It is a difference in C/C++ that i was unaware of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *general* syntax for `typedef` is

```
 typedef type-declaration      alias-name;
          |                     |
          |                     |
          |                     |
 typedef struct {int a; }      test; //2nd one is correct
          |                     |              
          |                     |
 typedef struct test { int a;}    ;  //You missed the synonym/alias name here
```

**Edit**

See  Eric Postpischil comments below

You'll just get a `warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration`

Ref: -[this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3783016/1870232)

Comment: A Microsoft document is **not** authoritative about C. The C standard does not actually contain a separate syntax for `typedef`. `typedef` shares the same syntax as other declarations, and that syntax does not actually require a declarator. The requirement for a declarator is actually a constraint, not part of the formal grammar, per C 2011 (N1570) 6.7 2: “A declaration other than a static_assert declaration shall declare at least a declarator (other than the parameters of a function or the members of a structure or union), a tag, or the members of an enumeration.”

Answer (score 2):

When you use `typedef` with structures, the `typedef` name is put *after* the structure. That's how C is specified to work.

If you use the first (without the `typedef` obviously), then you have to use the `struct` keyword, with the second you only have to use the name.

You can also use the same name for both the structure and the `typedef` like

```
typedef struct test { 
    int a;
} test;
```

Answer (score 1):

I conceptualize `typedef` as effectively working with two parameters:

```
typedef "original type"  "new type";
```

*(I know this is not 100% accurate, but it is a useful way to view it for simplicity)*

As in:

```
typedef unsigned int HRESULT;
// HRESULT is a new type that is the same as an unsigned int.
```

In your example:

```
typedef struct test { int a; }  (Missing Second Parameter!) ;
```

You've passed the first "param", a `struct` named `test`, but you never gave this type a new name with a second parameter.

What I think you want is:

```
typedef struct { int a; }  test;
```

Now you've taken a struct with a single field (`a`), and given it the name `test`.